# Grails error in debug mode

Tags: mysql, grails

I'm using eclipse and **Grails 2.5.1** with MySQL DB with driver version **5.1.36** and it is working fine in the **Run mode** , but when i try to use the **debug mode** i get the below error :

> context.GrailsContextLoaderListener , Error initializing the
>   application: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/MY_Dev

here is the BuildConfig :

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container   compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55.3" // or ":tomcat:8.0.22"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    // asset-pipeline 2.0+ requires Java 7, use version 1.9.x with Java 6
    compile ":asset-pipeline:2.2.3"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    //security plugin
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC5'
    compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
    compile ":mail:1.0.7"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
    compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"

    //internal mails plugin
    compile ":grails-direct-messages:1.0"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

and here is the DataSource:

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
jmxExport = true
driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
username = "sa"
password = ""
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class =   'org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional   context
   }

// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        //  dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop',   'update', 'validate', ''
        // url =   "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        pooled = true
        dbCreate = "create-drop"//create-drop
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "***"
        password = "***"
        url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/MY_Dev"
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        properties {
            // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
            jmxEnabled = true
            initialSize = 5
            maxActive = 50
            minIdle = 5
            maxIdle = 25
            maxWait = 10000
            maxAge = 10 * 60000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
            validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout = 3
            validationInterval = 15000
            testOnBorrow = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            testOnReturn = false
            jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
            defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        }
    }
}
}
```

any recommendations to solve this ?

Comment: Can you include your DataSource.groovy and BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: @Neoryder added them to the original post .

Comment: are you sure the url is not  url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MY_Dev"

Comment: Try a newer driver runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35'

Comment: @Neoryder what currently i'm using is 5.1.36